# makeindex via cli problem

Tags: build-system

I currently try to write my own buildscript as perl is at the moment not an option (so no makeglossaries) to build multiple glossaries.
When I try to pack everything in a single batch file, it seems that makeindex is not called (no gls files are created).

not working tex.bat:

```
@echo off

set document=%~n1
set miktexpath=C:/bin/programme/miktex/miktex/bin

start /wait %miktexpath%/pdflatex %document%.tex ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.glg -o %document%.gls %document%.glo ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.idx.glg -o %document%.idx.gls %document%.idx.glo ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/pdflatex %document%.tex ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/pdflatex %document%.tex ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/SumatraPDF -reuse-instance %document%.pdf
```

If I put every makeindex-call into a several batch file, it works.
But this is more ugly than it already is.

working tex.bat:

```
@echo off

set document=%~n1
set miktexpath=C:/bin/programme/miktex/miktex/bin

start /wait %miktexpath%/pdflatex %document%.tex ^
&& ^
call ./gls.bat %document% ^
&& ^
call ./gls_idx.bat %document% ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/pdflatex %document%.tex ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/pdflatex %document%.tex ^
&& ^
%miktexpath%/SumatraPDF -reuse-instance %document%.pdf
```

gls.bat:

```
@echo off

set document=%~n1
set miktexpath=C:/bin/programme/miktex/miktex/bin

%miktexpath%/makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.glg -o %document%.gls %document%.glo
```

gls_idx.bat:

```
@echo off

set document=%~n1
set miktexpath=C:/bin/programme/miktex/miktex/bin

%miktexpath%/makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.idx.glg -o %document%.idx.gls %document%.idx.glo
```

Why is that so and how do I write a single buildscript?

Another thing: `makeindex` also refuses to build files when I use file extensions other than `.gls`/`.glo` etc.

Comment: This really looks like a batch file question. That said, why are your trying to chain everything together into one enormous line? I'd normally do something like 1) run pdfTeX, 2) check the `ERRORLEVEL`, 3) assuming it's OK, run MakeIndex, 4) add loops as required.

Comment: I was just about to answer :-) I have a small working batch script if you want one (perhaps pop into the chat room for it?).

Comment: I've read your comment and with `errorlevel` I was able to do it within one single file. Thank you for editing

Comment: Perhaps a self-answer then?

Comment: In case it's of any interest, with newer versions of `glossaries` you can use the `automake` package option. If the shell escape is enabled, this will execute the required `makeindex` commands during the LaTeX run (without the need for the `makeglossaries` Perl script).

Answer (score 1):

Joseph Wright showed me [here his method](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17791170#17791170), that works as it should:

```
@echo off

set document=%~n1
set miktexpath=C:/bin/programme/miktex/miktex/bin

%miktexpath%/pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode %document%.tex
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ! Compilation failed
) else (
    %miktexpath%/makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.glg -o %document%.gls %document%.glo
    %miktexpath%/makeindex -s %document%.ist -t %document%.idx.glg -o %document%.idx.gls %document%.idx.glo
    %miktexpath%/pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode %document%.tex
    %miktexpath%/pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=batchmode %document%.tex
    %miktexpath%/SumatraPDF -reuse-instance %document%.pdf
)
```